# Outlook VBA, show meeting series expiring in the next 30 days

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to adapt an [outlook vba script](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ada40574-bad9-4c77-97e8-bb4298fd7a5c/recurring-meetings-expired-notice-sent-to-meeting-organizer-in-exchange-2010?forum=outlookdev) that shows if a named meeting series is expiring on that day.  I would like to make it look through all my meeting series, and show a reminder message for any when the end date is within the next 30 days.

Here is a start of what I currently have that will work if I supply the one meeting name (TestRecur):

```
Sub ExtendAppointmentSample()
 Dim myApptItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem
 Dim myRecurrPatt As Outlook.RecurrencePattern
 Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
 Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder
 Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
 Dim QuestionToMessageBox
  
 
 QuestionToMessageBox = "Appointment is about to expire, would you like to extend it?"
 
 Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set myFolder = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
 Set myItems = myFolder.Items
 ' specify the Item Object here but I would like it to cycle through all meeting series and look for those ending within 30 days
 Set myApptItem = myItems.Item("TestRecur")
 Set myRecurrPatt = myApptItem.GetRecurrencePattern
 
 If myRecurrPatt.PatternEndDate < DateAdd("d", 30, Date) Then
     YesOrNoAnswerToMessageBox = MsgBox(QuestionToMessageBox, vbInformation, "Extend")
    'Next line does not work; not sure how to get each Meeting Title
     'MsgBox (MeetingTitle)
    
 End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

> show meeting series expiring in the next 30 days

In that case you need to find all meetings that take place during these 30 days in the calendar. Then you can check their `PatternEndDate` property value when they ends. To get all calendar items for a specific time frame you can use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class. Read more about these methods in the articles that I wrote for the technical blog:

- [How To: Retrieve Outlook calendar items using Find and FindNext methods](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/11/outlook-retrieve-calendar-items/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method in Outlook to get calendar items](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/15/outlook-restrict-calendar-items/)

For example, you may use the following code to find appointments for a specific time frame (VB.NET):

```
Private Sub FindActiveAppointments(folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder)
    Dim dateTimeStart As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt")
    Dim dt As DateTime = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, _
                                      DateTime.Now.Day, 23, 59, 0, 0)
    Dim dateTimeEnd As String = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt")
    Dim searchCriteria As String = "[Start]<=""" + dateTimeEnd + """ AND [End]>=""" + _
                                                                dateTimeStart + """"
    Dim strBuilder As StringBuilder = Nothing
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    Dim appItem As Outlook._AppointmentItem = Nothing
    Dim folderItems As Outlook.Items = Nothing
    Dim resultItem As Object = Nothing
  
        folderItems = folder.Items
        folderItems.IncludeRecurrences = True
        folderItems.Sort("[Start]")
        If (folderItems.Count > 0) Then
            resultItem = folderItems.Find(searchCriteria)
            If Not IsNothing(resultItem) Then
                strBuilder = New StringBuilder()
                Do
                    If (TypeOf (resultItem) Is Outlook._AppointmentItem) Then
                        counter += 1
                        appItem = resultItem
                        strBuilder.AppendLine("#" + counter.ToString() + _
                                              " Subbject: " + appItem.Subject + _
                                              " Organizer: " + appItem.Organizer + _
                                              " Location: " + appItem.Location)
                    End If
                   
                    resultItem = folderItems.FindNext()
                Loop Until IsNothing(resultItem)
            End If
        End If
        If Not IsNothing(strBuilder) Then
            Debug.WriteLine(strBuilder.ToString())
        Else
            Debug.WriteLine("There is no match in the " + _
                               folder.Name + " folder.")
        End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Checks the end date of all recurring items.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ExtendAppointmentSample()

    Dim myApptItem As AppointmentItem
    Dim myRecurrPatt As RecurrencePattern
    Dim newPatternEndDate As Date
 
    Dim myFolder As Folder
    Dim myItems As Items
    Dim myRestrictedItems As Items
    
    Dim QuestionToMessageBox As String
        
    Set myFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
    Set myItems = myFolder.Items
    
    Dim strFilter As String
    strFilter = "[IsRecurring] = TRUE"
    Debug.Print "strFilter .....: " & strFilter
    
    Set myRestrictedItems = myItems.Restrict(strFilter)
    Debug.Print "myRestrictedItems.Count: " & myRestrictedItems.count
  
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To myRestrictedItems.count
 
        If myRestrictedItems(i).Class = olAppointment Then
    
            Set myApptItem = myRestrictedItems(i)
            Set myRecurrPatt = myApptItem.GetRecurrencePattern
 
            If myRecurrPatt.PatternEndDate < DateAdd("d", 30, Date) Then
            
                Debug.Print "myApptItem.subject: " & myApptItem.subject
                Debug.Print " myRecurrPatt.PatternEndDate....: " & myRecurrPatt.PatternEndDate
                
                newPatternEndDate = DateAdd("d", 30, myRecurrPatt.PatternEndDate)
                
                QuestionToMessageBox = myApptItem.subject & " is about to expire " & _
                  myRecurrPatt.PatternEndDate & "." & vbCr & _
                  "Would you like to extend it to " & newPatternEndDate & "?"
                
                If MsgBox(QuestionToMessageBox, vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Extend") = vbYes Then
                    myRecurrPatt.PatternEndDate = newPatternEndDate
                    
                    myApptItem.Save
                    
                    Debug.Print " New myRecurrPatt.PatternEndDate: " & myRecurrPatt.PatternEndDate
                End If
    
            End If
        End If
    Next
    
    Debug.Print "Done."
    
End Sub
```